# Assigning Docker container to bridge network - Conflicts with existing route

Tags: docker, networking, containers

When trying to assign a Docker container to my newly created bridge network, created using default parameters like so:

```
docker network create myBridge
```

And afterwards assigning it to one of my containers:

```
docker network connect myBridge containerName
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Failed to add interface vetha4a00de to sandbox: error setting interface "vetha4a00de" IP to 172.21.0.3/16: cannot program address 172.21.0.3/16 in sandbox interface because it conflicts with existing route {Ifindex: 517 Dst: 172.21.0.0/16 Src: 172.21.0.1 Gw: Flags: [] Table: 254}
```

I have no existing networks using this subnet, and I've even tried defining a completely different subnet upon creation, but it still gives me the same message.

The same happens when assigning the containers to the default bridge network - and they seem to only work when using the *host* network. Is there something I'm missing here? Shouldn't I be able to assign a container to a bridge network by doing this?

Comment: How did you initially start the container?

Comment: Using --network host

Comment: That basically disables Docker's network stack; I think you need to delete and recreate the container with `--network myBridge`.  (I don't think a single container can use multiple [network drivers](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers); you can't both use host networking and a Docker-internal bridge network.)